# Desktop browser showing different than mobile

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to create a responsive/adaptive webpage. I'm shrinking the desktop browser size and it does not have the same layout as the mobile browser. They are both using the same media query because the header text is red in both.

I'm not sure if this is a media query problem (I've tried many different media query setups) or if it's a flexbox issue. Any obvious possible issues or ideas?

**html:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**The media query I'm currently using:**

```
@media all and (min-width: 21.875rem)
```

**I'm using all the prefixes via a mixin:**

```
@mixin flexbox() {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

[Desktop browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr44o.png)

[Mobile browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDXqa.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634203/flexbox-columns-stacking-in-mobile-width-in-firefox-chrome-but-not-safari-desk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed not only the flexbox prefixes but also the prefixes for all the different flexbox attributes.

So I needed all of these mixins too:

```
@mixin flex($values) {
  -webkit-box-flex: $values;
  -moz-box-flex:  $values;
  -webkit-flex:  $values;
  -ms-flex:  $values;
  flex:  $values;
}

@mixin flex-flow($values) {
  -webkit-flex-flow: $values;  
  -ms-flex-flow: $values;     
  flex-flow: $values;
}

@mixin align-items($val) {
  -webkit-align-items: $val;  
  -ms-flex-align: $val;     
  align-items: $val;
}

@mixin align-self($val) {
  -webkit-align-self: $val;  
  -ms-flex-item-align: $val;     
  align-self: $val;
}

@mixin order($val) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: $val;  
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: $val;     
  -ms-flex-order: $val;     
  -webkit-order: $val;  
  order: $val;
}

@mixin justify-content($val) {
  -webkit-justify-content: $val;  
  -ms-flex-pack: $val;     
  flex-content: $val;
}
```